# Trying to add nodes to linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

We've started with linked list and nodes in class and I think I understood how they work. But at one part, where we have to add the node to the linked list, I'm having some issues to get it to work.
The mistake occurs in the method "append". My IDE doesn't tell me much about the issue.

My class LinkedList:

```
public class LinkedList {
    public Node head = null;

    public void insert(Node n) {
        n.next = head;
        head = n;
    }

    public Node search(int nummer) {
        Node current = head;

        while (current != null) {
            if (current.element == nummer)
                return current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int count() {
        int c = 0;

        for (Node n = head; n != null; n = n.next) {
            c++;
        }
        return c;
    }

    public void append(Node n) {
        if (head == null){
            head = new Node(n, null);
        }
        else {
            Node p = head;
            while (p.a != null){
                p = (Node) p.a;
            }
        p.a = new Node(n, null);}
    }    
}
```

My Node-class:

```
public class Node {
    public int element = 0;
    public Node next = null;
    Object a;

    public Node(int e, Node n) {
    this.element = e;
    this.next = n;
    }

    public Node(int e) {
    this.element = e;
    }

}
```

Comment: What issues are you having? What happens when you run your code? How does the result differ from what you want? At this point in your programming career, it is very critical to learn how to debug your own code. You should use a debugger or add `System.out.println()` statements to help you see what your code is actually doing. I also suggest that you draw pictures to visualize what you are doing. Use a box or circle to represent a node and arrows to represent the `next` reference between nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Your are treating the field `a` as if it were the pointer to the next node in the list.  It is not, it is actually the *data* contained in each list node.  Instead, modify your `append()` method to use `next`:

```
public void append(Node n) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node(n, null);
    }
    else {
        Node p = head;
        // walk down the list from the head until reaching the end
        while (p.next != null) {
            p = (Node) p.next;
        }
        // then append the new Node to the end of the list
        p.next = n;
    }
}
```

Note that ideally you should have getter and setter methods for your `Node` class.  I might suggest something like this:

```
public class Node {
    private int element = 0;   // no idea what this is for
    private Node next = null;
    private Object a;

    public Node(int e, Node n) {
        this.element = e;
        this.next = n;
    }

    public Node(int e) {
        this.element = e;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setA(Object a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public Object getA() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Using this updated definiton of `Node` your `append()` method would become:

```
public void append(Node n) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node(n, null);
    }
    else {
        Node p = head;
        // walk down the list from the head until reaching the end
        while (p.getNext() != null) {
            p = p.getNext();
        }
        // then append the new Node to the end of the list
        p.setNext(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your updated version, but the issue still occurs. n in "new Node(n, null), says now "Node cannot converted to int".

Comment: That's all code that exists and I've looked for the error so many times.

Comment: Found the error, sorry.  Just use `p.setNext(n)`, and directly append the new `Node`.